# When linking, how to find out which source lib refers to an non-existing target lib

Tags: visual-c++, linker

I realize I have to cope with such a problem. Using Visual C++ 2008 to compile an old program, I got error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBC.lib'
```

After checking the VC project setting, I believe that this is caused by an old lib(which will be linked to the final EXE) compiled from the era of Visual C++ 6 that have LIBC.LIB link-directive embedded(caused by `cl /ML...` ).

Because there are quite a few libs added in my project, I think I need **a quick way to find out** which lib(s) contains the LIBC.LIB link-directive so that I can fix those libs to use `/MT` .

BTW: Using `/NODEFAULTLIB:LIBC.LIB` linker option as a solution is not decent because there exists binary interface incompatibility between single threaded CRT and multithreaded CRT.

Comment: Doesn't the [`/VERBOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) option give you what you need?

Comment: I tried ``/VERBOSE:LIB`` and ``/VERBOSE:REF`` but no clear indication of LIBC.LIB's reference source.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure because I have not developped in VisualStudio for some time, but the `dumpbin` tool might give you pertinent information about you libraries. Being a command line tool, you can easily capture its output in a text file and search in it.

Comment: Sounds like a feasible solution when there is no known better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try dependency walker.
http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: No. dependency walker works for DLL, not lib. You link EXE with lib, not with DLL.